# Connect NodeMCU 0.9 to WPA2 Enterprise

Tags: wifi, esp8266

Is there a way to connect to a NodeMCU 0.9 to **WPA2 Enterprise** like Eduroam?

Now I'm using the Arduino IDE 1.8.5 with the library: *ESP8266WiFi.h*

In this way I simply connect to a personal WPA2 with pre-shared key:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
const char* ssid = "ssid";
const char* password = "password";

void connectToWifi() {
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
  }
  Serial.print("Connected as "+WiFi.localIP());
}
```

EDIT:
Here some more information about Eduroam:

```
network={
ssid="eduroam"
proto=WPA RSN
key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
auth_alg=OPEN
pairwise=CCMP TKIP
eap=TLS
ca_cert="~/ca.pem"
private_key="~/wifiCert.p12"
private_key_passwd="myPassw0rd"
phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
identity="My@Identity.com"
}
```

`ca.pem` and `wifiCert.p12` are 2 certificate needed to login.

Comment: @Bence The way I read it is that connecting to a standard WPA2 network is fine, but WPA2 Enterprise networks don't work as expected. Timmy, is this what you meant? Could you clarify exactly what happens when you try to connect to an Enterprise network?

Comment: @Aurora0001 Yes, you are right, I'm trying to connect to a WPA2 Enterprise but I don't know how to set my certificate